# How to get clarity on the reason for question closure so that question can be improved?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

How can I find out why a question was closed so as to improve the question?

I just had a question closed [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/73365/looking-for-references-to-political-moral-philosophy-literature-on-communal-chil?noredirect=1#comment205460_73365). The reason given is that it "needs more focus." At the bottom I reproduce what it says in the rules about that reason. It is unclear to me in what respect my question needs more focus. How can I determine the respect in which it is thought to need more focus?

> Needs more focus - if your question has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it probably needs to be more focused to be successful in our format.
>
> > Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.